# fork mulitple child in one parent

Tags: c++, fork

I want to fork three child process in one parent.
And the following is my C++ code:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    pid_t pid;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        pid = fork();

        if (pid < 0)
        {
            cout << "Fork Error";
            return -1;
        }
        else if (pid == 0)
            cout << "Child " << getpid() << endl;
        else
        {
            wait(NULL);
            cout << "Parent " << getpid() << endl;
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Now my output is :

```
Child 27463
Child 27464
Child 27465
Parent 27464
Parent 27463
Parent 27462
```

How should I modify my program to get the output like the following?

```
Child 27463
Child 27464
Child 27465
Parent 27462
```

What I mean is that these THREE children need to belong to the same ONE parent, can anybody give me some suggestion ?

Thank you all. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should exit the execution of the child processes. Otherwise, they continue forking also

```
pid_t pid;
for(i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    pid = fork();
    if(pid < 0) {
        printf("Error");
        exit(1);
    } else if (pid == 0) {
        cout << "Child " << getpid() << endl;
        exit(0); 
    } else  {
        wait(NULL);
        cout << "Parent " << getpid() << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues:

- children zero and one continue with the `for` loop, spawning further processes;
- the "parent" branch terminates instead of continuing with the loop.

The following will produce the output you want:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    pid_t pid;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        pid = fork();

        if (pid < 0)
        {
            cout << "Fork Error";
            return -1;
        }
        else if (pid == 0) {
            cout << "Child " << getpid() << endl;
            return 0;
        } else {
            wait(NULL);
            if (i == 2) {
                cout << "Parent " << getpid() << endl;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I run it, I get

```
Child 4490
Child 4491
Child 4492
Parent 4489
```

Answer (score 0):

Move your `return 0` from the last condition to the middle one:

```
    if (pid < 0)
    {
        cout << "Fork Error";
        return -1;
    }
    else if (pid == 0) {
        cout << "Child " << getpid() << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        wait(NULL);
        cout << "Parent " << getpid() << endl;

    }
```

This way the parent will continue to loop, and the children will terminate instead of looping.